# Convert click to onmouseover javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change click event to an onmouseover event to open a my div and then if mouse goes left my div hide again , like a dropdown menu, can anyone help me please.

HTML code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Papermashup.com | Sliding Div</title>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="dropdown/drop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="dropdown/drop.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>

<body>
 <a href="#" class="show_hide" onmouseover="this.#" >Show/hide</a><br />
    <div class="slidingDiv" style="width:103px;height:60px;">
        <img alt="" height="80" src="images/dropdown.png" width="103">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
.show_hide {
    display:none;
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click( function() {
         $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: Whats stopping you changing the `a` `onmouseover` event to `onclick`?

Comment: @Mohamamdreza: Why cant you use onclick directly? If you want it so badly then you can use event.initMouseEvent() to simulate an click event in place of mouseover.

Comment: actually i want to create a dropdown menu with this , so i want to show div when mouse goes over my button and i want to hide div when mouse goes left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 $(".show_hide").mouseenter(function() {
       $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
  })
```

Comment: thank u dude , is there any solution to if mouse left div go hide again ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) binding instead of the click binding.

```
$('.show_hide').mouseover(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: thank u dude , is there any solution to if mouse left div go hide again ? i want to create something like dropdown menu

Comment: I edited my answer to show the [mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) binding in action.